# Calculate software metrics for PHP projects

Tags: php, metrics, code-metrics

I would like to calculate some code metrics for my PHP OOP projects. I try to use some of the tools mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60394/calculate-code-metrics). But except trail version of [Understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60394/calculate-code-metrics), which presents only

- number of code, comment, blank lines
- number of classes number of file
- number of functions number of
- declarative/executable statements

I couldn't find any working for PHP.

[Plugin for Eclipse by State of Flow](http://eclipse-metrics.sourceforge.net/) is not working with my (not so new) Galileo Eclipse v3.5.

I'm interested in measures such as

- depth of inheritance tree,
- avg function length,
- weighted methods per class,
- duplications,
- ...

Are there any tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PHP Depend](http://pdepend.org/) generates some nice metrics for you.

Answer (score 11):

There are some tools, in PHP -- and for PHP code.

Here are those I can think about :

- [**`phpcpd`**](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpcpd) -- copy-paste detector
- [**`phploc`**](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phploc) -- to do many kind of counts *(lines, classes, ...)*
- [**`PHP_CodeSniffer`**](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/redirected) -- to check if your code respects your coding standards.
- [**`phpmd`**](http://phpmd.org/) -- mess detector
- [**`phpDocumentor`**](http://www.phpdoc.org/) / [**DocBlox**](http://www.docblox-project.org/) to generate documentation *(and detect what is not properly documented)*

In PHP, those tools are generally not used from Eclipse, but integrated in some Continuous Integration Platform.

About those, you can take a look at :

- [**phpUnderControl**](http://phpundercontrol.org/) -- was used a lot a couple of years ago -- it has less success now
- [**Jenkins**](http://jenkins-ci.org/) *(More or less a fork of Hudson)*

  - And, for that one, see [Template for Jenkins Jobs for PHP Projects](http://jenkins-php.org/)

Still, if you want to integrate some of those tools with Eclipse PDT, you might want to take a look at [PHP Tool Integration](http://www.phpsrc.org/projects/pti).

Answer (score 2):

See our [PHP CloneDR](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone/PHPCloneDR.html) for a tool that computes the amount and the precise location of duplicated code.  It will find duplicates in spite of reformatting the text, modification of comments, and modifications (up to a degree of [dis]similarity.

There's an example of Joomla processed by the PHP CloneDR at the link.

Comment: phpcpd does also find duplicates if you reformat code and comments.

Comment: @cweiske: And who on earth will go through his big application and do that just to make phpcpd work?   You don't need to do any manual labor like that to run the CloneDR.

Answer (score 2):

to get complexity (and more, even estimated development time) you can use [ProjectCodeMeter](http://www.projectcodemeter.com) which supports PHP as well as other programming languages.

Comment: Thanks - looks interesting, i will try it!