# Calculate average line of code of a specific file type in a GIT repository

Tags: git

Is there any way to find out what is the average Line Of Code number of a specific file type in a git repository ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60394/calculate-code-metrics

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no git-specific functionality for this.. you will have to write your own method for that...

Maybe take a look here: [Count number of lines in a git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822471/count-number-of-lines-in-a-git-repository)